# How to run rsync using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

This is part of my ansible playbook

```
    - name: Create a new regular user with sudo privileges
      user:
        name: "{{ create_user }}"
        state: present
        groups: wheel
        append: true
        create_home: true
        shell: /bin/bash

    - name: Execute rsync command so the new user has the same authorized keys as root user
      ansible.builtin.shell: rsync --archive --chown\=={{ create_user }}:{{ create_user }} ~/.ssh /home/{{ create_user }}

    - name: Set authorized key for remote user
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ create_user }}"
        state: present
        key: "{{ copy_local_key }}"
```

I have tested the original rsync command which is run at the target node as `root`

`rsync --archive --chown\=sammy:sammy ~/.ssh /home/sammy`

This was definitely working if I had done this manually as `root` at the target node.

The error message I got was

```
TASK [Create a new regular user with sudo privileges] **************************
changed: [server1]

TASK [Execute rsync command so the new user has the same authorized keys as root user] ***
fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: --chown\\= Supported parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, stdin_add_newline, strip_empty_ends, warn"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server1                    : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

My ansible version when I run `ansible --version`

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/sammy/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

My vars/default.yml

```
---
create_user: sammy
copy_local_key: "{{ lookup('file', lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
sys_packages: ["curl", "vim", "git", "ufw"]
```

What can I do to make this work?

### UPdate

Tried this and failed

```
- name: Execute rsync command so the new user has the same authorized keys as root user
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: rsync --archive --chown\=={{ create_user }}:{{ create_user }} ~/.ssh /home/{{ create_user }}
```

error message is

```
TASK [Execute rsync command so the new user has the same authorized keys as root user] ***
fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: cmd Supported parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, stdin_add_newline, strip_empty_ends, warn"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server1                    : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Are you aware ansible has a [`synchronize` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) that wraps arround rsync ? Regarding your exact error, ansible thinks `chown` is a parameters to the `command` module (passed as old ini style) . Did you try to quote your entire command ? Might be easier to user a folded scalar block indicator (`>`) for a quick test.

Comment: @Zeitounator I'm sorry I'm really new to ansible. would u mind rewriting it in full just for that task so I can test it out? By the way my rsync is between the root user and the {{ create_user }} of the same target node

Comment: @Zeitounator i figured it out. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

cannot use rsync directly but can use synchronize module but this means need to install something called ansible.posix as a separate collection.

I think it's like a plugin.

Anyway, assuming the playbook is in folder `ubuntu2004/00_setup` on the control node

Go to folder holding the playbook.yml

```
cd ubuntu2004/00_setup
```

One time effort (I think?) to install ansible.posix

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
```

Warning if you don't install this you wll get this error message when you run the new playbook

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'ansible.posix.synchronize'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/sammy/ansible-playbooks/ubuntu2004/00_setup/playbook.yml': line 38, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: Execute rsync command
      ^ here
```

New playbook.yml note the two new tasks
one runs the synchronize while the other recursively chowns `/home/{{ create_user }}/.ssh`

```
# User + Key Setup
    - name: Create a new regular user with sudo privileges
      user:
        name: "{{ create_user }}"
        state: present
        groups: wheel
        append: true
        create_home: true
        shell: /bin/bash

    - name: Execute rsync command so new user has the same authorized keys as root
      ansible.posix.synchronize:
        src: /root/.ssh
        dest: /home/{{ create_user }}
      delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

    - name: Change .ssh file permission
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /home/{{ create_user }}/.ssh
        state: directory
        recurse: yes
        owner: "{{ create_user }}"
        group: "{{ create_user }}"

    - name: Set authorized key for remote user
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ create_user }}"
        state: present
        key: "{{ copy_local_key }}"
```

Run the playbook

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -l server1 -u root
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you need to use the "cmd:" parameter for the "ansible.builtin.shell:" module so Ansible can parse your command line.

Your play would look like this:

```
    - name: Execute rsync command so the new user has the same authorized keys as root user
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: rsync --archive --chown\={{ create_user }}:{{ create_user }} ~/.ssh /home/{{ create_user }}
```

FWIW, I'm using Ansible 2.10.4 on Fedora 33

Comment: somewhat of the same error. please see my udpated question

Comment: I have already solved my situation. Your answer might still work under a different circumstances I'm unsure. In any case I appreciate the time taken to answer. I will mark my own answer as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question but I had to fix a similar issue myself today and my answer might help others.

I got exactly the same error `Unsupported parameters for (command) module..` when calling something like `ansible.builtin.shell: rsync ..` on a machine where I have Ansible 2.9.x.

I used to run the same playbook without any issues on several other machines with Ansible 4.7.x

The solution was to switch the fully-qualified name of `ansible.builtin.shell: rsync..` to just `shell: rsync..`.

This simple solution worked on both Ansible 2.9.x and 4.7.x while the fully-qualified name worked only on 4.7.x (actually it works from 2.10 on, see below)

Starting with Ansible 2.10 it is recommended to use the fully-qualified collection name in your playbooks (see this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html)

Indeed, if you look at the documentation and the usage examples for the shell module you will notice the difference between versions 2.9 and 2.10:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/shell_module.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/modules/shell_module.html

According to my experience so far, using fully-qualified names for ansible<=2.9 or non-fully qualified names for ansible>=2.10 doesn't mean that you will automatically get errors. But sometimes (like in your case) you will get some issues so it is better to stick with the recommended syntax for each version.

So, in your case, if you want to stick with ansible 2.9 and don't want to install `ansible.posix`, just don't use the fully-qualified name of `shell`.